# What is the best way to approach age verification?

Tags: javascript, cookies, checkbox, verification

I want to verify that everyone that visit my website is least 18 years old. What would be the best approach in order to do it?

I think that the best approach is to send a cookie after the user clicks over the checkbox. Is there any better way to do this?

Example:

[image: checkbox verification]

Comment: What happens when someone is behind a proxy server or VPN that is shared among many people? Your IP address approach wouldn't work.

Comment: `... that visit any website ...` this *"any"* gets me. What are we talking about? Securing your page from minors, or ensuring that some minor that uses your computer doesn't access ... well, whatever?

Comment: with "any website page" I mean all pages like www.mywebsite.com ,   www.mywebsite.com/contact-us ,  www.mywebsite.com/blog etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into 3rd party authentication services like Auth0 (https://auth0.com/). I find if you allow people to use Social Networks that require their age, you are more likely to collect verified information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies for this :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could also use localStorage instead of cookies. It stores data on the client side with no expiration date. It gets erased only through js or when the user clears his browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save this information in cookies and yes you can check if there is such an information available on the user's browser. (in php for eg. very simple)

The IP check is not a great idea. Just think about dinamic IP-s (same user with different IP next time) and storing sensitive data.